# How to Split an Array Element into 2 and Return a New Array with Original Element dissected?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, split

I am doing a programming challenge and am struggling with one question.

Here is the challenge:

1. First, declare an array named myArray
2. Great! Now populate myArray with two strings.
   Put your full name in the first string, and your Skype handle in the second.
3. Next, declare a function named cutName. It should take a string as an argument.
4. cutName should return an array by breaking up the input string into individual words. For example "Douglas Crockford" should be returned as ["Douglas", "Crockford"]
5. Make a new empty object literal named myData
6. Add three key-value pairs to myData, by following these guidelines
   6.1. fullName : call cutName on the name string stored in myArray
   6.2. skype : refer to your Skype handle in myArray
   6.3. github : If you have a github handle, enter it as a string. If not, set this to null

This was my answer:

```
var myArray = ["Arthur Philadelpho", "arthurphiladelpho"];

function cutName (myArray){
  var res = myArray[0].split(" ");  //This is the problem.
};

var myData = {
             fullname:myArray[0], 
             skype:myArray[1], 
             github:null
};
```

I couldn't solve question 4 but now it is solved.

My new issue is question 6.1.

Is there any angel online that would shed me some light?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

cutName should take a string as an argument. you currently have it defined as taking an array.  change your function to:

```
function cutName (myString){ return myString.split(" "); }
```

this function takes a string and returns an array

Comment: Thanks devlin, this way works! I am having a new issue now: question 6.1: do you have any cosiderations?

Comment: What is the new array's name? And how may I call it now?

Comment: @ArthurPhiladelpho - assign it to a variable when you call the function, like so:  `var myCutNameArray = cutName(myString);`  the new array will be assigned to myCutNameArray.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cutName( string ){
 return string.split(' ');
}
```

You need to make your function take in a string and return an array. Split will return an array by default.

Comment: There shouldn't be a semicolon at the end of a function declaration.

Comment: Nice catch, mustn't have been paying attention.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, after removing the semi colon after the function it works! I am having a new issue now: question 6.1: do you have any cosiderations?

Comment: What is the new array's name? And how may I call it now?

Comment: It will depend whether you store the new array as a variable or if you simply call the function directly. 

For example you can call the new array whatever you like by calling:

var newArray = cutName( myArray[0] );

myData = { fullName: newArray[0], .... }

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I tried what you advised but haven't been successful. I defined the newArray right under the function -> is this what you meant?

Comment: When you call the function cutName you need to pass it the first index of the array. You wrote this cutName( myArray) when you should have written cutName( myArray[0] )

Comment: This is where I stand with my ignorance:

var myArray = ["Arthur Philadelpho", "arthurphiladelpho"];

function cutName (myArray[0]){return myArray.split(" "); } 

 var newArray = cutName( myArray[0] );

var myData = {fullname:newArray[0], skype:myArray[1], github:null};

Comment: You aren't understanding the way functions are defined. The function cutName should not have any reference to your array.

`var myArray = ["Arthur Philadelpho", "arthurphiladelpho"];

function cutName(string){
 return string.split(" ");  
};

var newArray = cutName(myArray[0]);

var myData = {
 fullname: newArray[0], 
 skype: myArray[1], 
 github:null
};`

Only when you "call" the function will you use the myArray as an argument

Comment: Ok understood. I just still haven't understood the question 6.1 fullName : call cutName on the name string stored in myArray. The program is not accepting your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Then this is all you need:
`var myArray = ["Arthur Philadelpho", "arthurphiladelpho"]; function cutName(string){ return string.split(" "); }; var myData = { fullname: cutName(myArray[0]), skype: myArray[1], github:null };`